# C# WPF non-client area иконки

Tags: c#, wpf

Как получить стандартные пиктограммы окна?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

программы типа Google Chrome полностью перерабатывают non-client area  и добавляют стандартные пиктограммы или каким-то образом редактируют ее?

Comment: В каком виде вы хотите их получить и для чего?

Comment: @Kromster мне нужна стандартная non-client area с моими кнопками